# Android Vector Drawable not same as SVG Path

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

created an svg icon (which work great) but, when displayed in android as a vector drawable, one of the path does not render the same.
Here is the original svg path:

```
<path
   d="m 34.424316,19.525423 0,-1.2854 -2.329101,0 0,-0.604248 2.449951,-3.479004 
0.53833,0 0,3.479004 0.725098,0 0,0.604248 -0.725098,0 0,1.2854 -0.65918,0 z m 
0,-1.889648 0,-2.420655 -1.680908,2.420655 1.680908,0 z"
   style="fill:#FF00FF"
   id="path3383" />
```

this is what it looks like :

[image: svg path]

The android path:

```
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF00FF"
    android:pathData="M 34.424316,19.525423 l 0,-1.2854 -2.329101,0 0,-0.604248
2.449951,-3.4790040.53833,0 0,3.479004 0.725098,0 0,0.604248 -0.725098,0 0,1.2854 -0.65918,0 z m
0,-1.889648 0,-2.420655 -1.680908,2.420655 1.680908,0 z" />
```

And how it look like :

[image: android path]

P.S. android studio make it blurred but that is not a problem, it renders as sharp as it should on Android lollipop.

The problem is that the hole in the 4 is filled. Even if both path are mostly identical (the only difference is an added 'l' after the first coordinates. But if i remove it the 4 does not render at all).

Comment: did you try to see it in your app?

Comment: It is actually part of the icon of my app. But yes, in a real android phone (lollipop) the hole is closed.

Comment: it cannot work: what is "-3.4790040.53833" in your pathData? it is not any valid float number

Comment: There is a space between the -3.479004 and the new line. It just a mistake in copy pasting (ps. i corrected it in the question)

Comment: I used a tool to convert my file. And as i said, if i remove the 'l' the 4 disappear. for the M, if i put a lower case one, the 4 isn't in the right place anymore (it goes at about the vertical middle right aligned).

Comment: try: L 2.329101,5.3621826 2.329101,4.0767574 0,4.0767574 0,3.472455 2.449951,-0.00654572 2.988281,-0.00654572 2.988281,3.472455 3.713379,3.472455 3.713379,4.0767574 2.988281,4.0767574 2.988281,5.3621826 2.329101,5.3621826 z L 2.329101,3.472455 2.329101,1.0518542 0.648193,3.472455 2.329101,3.472455 z

Comment: Thanks pskink. it works. How did you fixed it?

Comment: inkscape + animal instinct

Answer (score 1):

There are no command characters in the pathdata of your post. What the questioner says "l" was introduced after the first set of coordinates is actually the first command character after "M  ". As per documentation if the command character is same as previous then it can be omitted to save space. But here the "l" referred to by the questioner is the first "l" after "M" (move to) command character. "l" is "line to" command character. It being the first in this case cannot be omitted.   I repaired the file and am giving the contents of the file below.

I am showing the second pathdata of your post shifted to left by 10 pixels (  M   24.424316,  19.525423)
I changed the fillColor to blue.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:viewportWidth="40.0"
        android:viewportHeight="40.0">



    <path
        android:pathData="


     m  34.424316,   19.525423
     l   0,          -1.2854
     l  -2.329101,    0
     l   0,          -0.604248
     l   2.449951,   -3.479004
     l   0.53833,     0
     l   0,           3.479004
     l   0.725098,    0
     l   0,           0.604248
     l  -0.725098,    0
     l   0,           1.2854
     l  -0.65918,     0

     m   0,          -1.889648
     l   0,          -2.420655
     l  -1.680908,    2.420655
     l   1.680908,    0      "


    android:strokeLineCap="square"
    android:strokeColor="#ffff00ff"
    android:fillColor="#ff0000ff"
    android:strokeWidth="0.2"/>

    <path
    android:pathData="


    M   24.424316,  19.525423
    l    0,         -1.2854
    l   -2.329101,   0
    l    0,         -0.604248
    l    2.449951,  -3.479004
    l    0.53833,    0
    l    0,          3.479004
    l    0.725098,   0
    l    0,          0.604248
    l   -0.725098,   0
    l    0,          1.2854
    l   -0.65918,    0

    m    0,         -1.889648
    l    0,         -2.420655
    l   -1.680908,   2.420655
    l    1.680908,   0 "

    android:strokeLineCap="square"
    android:strokeColor="#ffff00ff"
    android:fillColor="#ff0000ff"
    android:strokeWidth="0.2"/>

</vector>
```

Create a blank xml file and copy the above contents into it . Then you should see the number 4 (twice) with magenta outline and blue fill. I did it here and the display is sharp. I do not know the reasons for blurring referred by the questioner.

Comment: Pasting path data from svg to vector in Android Studio gives a lot of useful info *"Very long vector path (1965 characters), which is bad for performance. Considering reducing precision, removing minor details or rasterizing vector. less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Using long vector paths is bad for performance. There are several ways to make the pathData shorter: * Using less precision * Removing some minor details * Using the Android Studio vector conversion tool * Rasterizing the image (converting to PNG)"*

Answer (score 0):

VectorDrawable **fill-rule** is always **nonzero** and cannot be changed. If you end up with areas filled that should not be filled, that is because the SVG image was created using even-odd rule instead. There are two ways to fix this problem: manually edit SVGs in vector graphics software or use the **BetterVectorDrawable** library in your app.

Read more [here](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter)